# Find and replace only filtered rows in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which uses a search function to filter rows in the table. i already have a functioning find and replace but it replaces all cell values in the table that matches the search ignoring the filter. I'm trying to create a find and replace function that only processes filtered cells. i usually use pure javascript but from research it seems only selecting visible elements is a job for jQuery. i've found a script on stackoverflow that i've tried editing for this purpose but i cannot get it to function properly.

I am wondering if it possible to use this type of function on only visible elements in the DOM?

```js
    $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 8 ) {
              var $rows = $('#table tr');
      var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $rows
        .show()
        .filter(function() {
          var $inputs = $(this).find("input");
          var found = searchText.toLowerCase().length == 0; // for empty search, show all rows
          for (var i=0; i < $inputs.length && !found; i++) {
            var text = $inputs.eq(i).val().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            found = text.toLowerCase().length > 0 && text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) >= 0;
          }
          return !found;
       })
       .hide();
    };
  })

  function submit(){

  var replace = document.getElementById("replace").value;
  var find = new RegExp(document.getElementById('find').value, 'gi')
  $("tr, td").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace(find,replace);
    $(this).text(text);
});}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Find" id="find">
  <input id="replace"  type="text" placeholder="Replace">
    <button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
    <input id="search" placeholder="Search">

  <table id="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><input id="input1"></td>
      <td><input id="input2"></td>
      <td><input id="input3"></td>
      <td><input id="input4"></td>
      <td><input id="input5"></td>
      <td><input id="input6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input id="input1"></td>
      <td><input id="input2"></td>
      <td><input id="input3"></td>
      <td><input id="input4"></td>
      <td><input id="input5"></td>
      <td><input id="input6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input id="input1"></td>
      <td><input id="input2"></td>
      <td><input id="input3"></td>
      <td><input id="input4"></td>
      <td><input id="input5"></td>
      <td><input id="input6"></td>
      </tr>
      </body>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the [visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

**Wrong**

```
$("tr, td:visible").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace(find,replace);
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

**Correct**

```
$("tr, td").find("input:visible").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    text = text.replace(find,replace);
    $(this).val(text);
});
```

So the problem was that you were replacing the text of the cell, but the text it's an input, so in order to see the change you must modify the **value** of the input, as per snippet.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/320194/)

Comment: this isn't working, it's just removing all rows in the table?

Comment: my snippet shouldn't affect the removing of the rows.
If you click submit on the snippet, leaving empty the "search" field, all the rows will be hidden, I think there is an error on your logic. the snippet that I posted should replace the strings only for the visible cells